# how can I put ion-item icon to the end of the row

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

This is my code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let column of columns" item-icon-right>

            {{column.title}}
            <ion-icon name="star" item-end></ion-icon>
        </ion-item>
```

What I need is to put icon to the far end of the row, but when I load the page, the icon is only to the right of the content, not float to the right of the whole row.

I followed ionic doc, but I can not find out their source code for the demo, for example: here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/, their code can not generate the demo effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use item-right:

```
<ion-icon name="star" item-right></ion-icon>
```